# Ubuntu 20.10 freezes after login

Tags: graphics, login, desktop-environments, 20.10

My Ubuntu boots correctly but after I enter my password and login it freezes for almost 20sec with cursor moving in purple background.
But after 20-25sec everything works fine.

I have also tried installing proper graphics drivers And that too not working.I also tried reinstalling Ubuntu-desktop and that too is not working.

Attachments:
[logs.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/173gTJ4NUfrZU0yT1YtiFTGW3Ux92BVas/view?usp=sharing)

Anyone please help me to resolve it.

Comment: Please, provide us some logs. `journalctl -b0 -p4 > logs.txt`, then publish content of `logs.txt` file in your question. Thanks!

Comment: "But after 20-25sec everything works fine." Maybe it is just loading normally, but slowly? What processor do you have? Do you have SSD or HDD? I have a fast processor with SSD, but I still see the same purple screen with mouse cursor, but only for a few seconds. Unfortunately there is this trend where user interface designers don't like to provide us with progress bars or loading indicators any more, like in the earlier days. Nowadays we are just supposed to know when something is still working in the background, or pretend we don't notice. It's happening in webdesign too. :|